# How to store session id as foreign key in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, session, foreign-keys

I have stores a unique session id in session when user logged in using session_regenerate_id() funciton . Every time user gets loged in in my website he will get a fresh session id.

now i want to save some of his data in a db table. I want to know how should i store data so that the new table gets foreign key from the user id of main table.
Because i want to relate that information with the user id that is stored in main table. I dont want to store main table ID column in session as user_id because of security.
Please all you big developers suggest me a good way in core PHP instead of frameworks.

Developers Will easily understand what i want to ask . I am a bit new :)

THANKS so much
Faysal

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask... fix the grammar

Comment: I just stored session like this

session_regenerate_id();
 
 $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

   $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $_SESSION['user_agent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
 $_SESSION['last_login'] = time();


there is a users table and a details table in db.
i want to store the details of loged in user in "details" table. 
Want to know what is the best way to store and relate both tables.
Although i haven't stored the users table ID in session.

Comment: Why do you need to details table? Why do you not store user ID in session?

Comment: Thats what i am asking. Is it safe to store ID column data of users table in session ? 
Isn't session hijacking possible if i do this ?

Comment: Yes, it is safe. Not storing user ID in the same table with other session data is not going to keep session hijacking from happening.

Comment: Awesome . Thanks so much for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using session, a random string is generated to identify a user - this string is called session ID. Session ID is stored in cookies. Cookies are sent to the web server with every request. On the server, session ID is then connected with session data.

Attacker can't change the session data, therefore, storing a user ID in session is not a security threat.

For cases when an attacker steals someone's session ID, for protection you can check if the user agent and IP address are the same as when session was created. If not, just destroy the session.

To identify a user, you need to connect session with a user. Doing so through a chain of tables in database doesn't provide any security.

Comment: Great, Understood. Thanks so much Sir.